Product of limits involving Dirac Delta functions
I'm currently working through a problem and I've come to a point at which I have to evaluate the following integral $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \int_0^\infty  -f(z, \tilde{\,z})\lim_{t \rightarrow 0}[G(t;x,z)\tilde{\,G}(t;y,\tilde{\,z})] \,dz\, d\tilde{\,z}.$$ We may take $x \geq 0$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$ as fixed, we have that $f$ is continuous and bounded, each of $G$ and $\tilde{\,G}$ are bounded for fixed $t$ away from $t=0$ and we also have the following two facts about the limits of $G$ and $\tilde{\,G}$ as $t$ tends to $0$ $$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} G(t;x,z) = \delta(x-z) \,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{and}\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \tilde{\,G}(t;y,\tilde{\,z}) = \delta(y-\tilde{\,z}).$$ Specifically $$G(t;x,z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{(x-z)^2}{2t}} \,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{and}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,  \tilde{\,G}(t;y,\tilde{\,z}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{(y-\tilde{\,z})^2}{2t}}.$$ Now, I'm wondering about the legitimacy of claiming \begin{align} \int_{-\infty}^\infty  \int_0^\infty  -f(z, \tilde{\,z})\lim_{t \rightarrow 0}[G(t;x,z)\tilde{\,G}(t;y,\tilde{\,z})] \,dz\, d\tilde{\,z} &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty  \int_0^\infty  -f(z, \tilde{\,z})\delta(x-z, y-\tilde{\,z})\,dz\, d\tilde{\,z} \\&= -f(x,y).\end{align}
Standard ideas of products of limits would say if one is zero when the other infinite then we can't separate them, however with this being a very "specific infinity", namely having the area under it at a point being equal to $1$, is there an argument one can make that the above claim is legitimate in this case? If we had $x=z$ but $y \neq \tilde{\,z}$ I feel as if the term $e^{-\frac{(y-\tilde{\,z})^2}{2t}}$ tending to zero would dominate the infinity of the $G$ term in the same way it does the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$ term, thus making the above claim valid, however I'm unsure if this is correct or how to argue this rigorously? Any insight would be much appreciated.

I think this post on the convergence of the heat kernel as $t\to 0$ is equivalent to your question

Just a quick note: you should probably write $\delta(x-z, y- \tilde{z}$, seeing it as a $2d$ delta function. Products of deltas are not defined. By the way, I also think the link posted by @whpowell96 should help

Yes this is helpful thank you

@user82832 Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.

If $Z\sim N(x,t)$ and $\tilde{Z}\sim N(y,t)$ the integral is $$I(t)=E((f(x+\sqrt{t}Z_1,y+\sqrt{t}Z_2)1_{Z_2 -y/\sqrt{t}})$$ where $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are independent and $N(0,1).$ We have
$$I(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\int_{-y/\sqrt{t}}f(x+\sqrt{t}z_1,y+\sqrt{t}z_2)e^{-z_2^2/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dz_2\right)e^{-z_1^2/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dz_1$$ If $f$ is bounded and continuous, by dominated convergence $I(t)\to f(x,y)$ if $y>0$ $I(t)\to 0$ if $y<0$ and $I(t)\to f(x,0)/2$ if $y=0.$

Thanks for the reply, why would it be $1_{Z_2 -y/\sqrt{t}}$ sorry? Would that not restrict $\tilde{,z}$ to being greater than $0$ rather than $z$? Thanks

The limits are taken to be distributional limits. That is to say that $\lim_{t\to 0^+}G(t;x,z)=\delta(x-z)$ means that for any $\phi(x)\in C_C^\infty$, we have
$$\lim_{t\to 0^+}\int_{-\infty}^\infty G(t;x,z)\phi(x)\,dx=\phi(z)$$
To see that this is true, we write
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{t\to0^+}\int_{-\infty}^\infty G(t;x,z)\phi(x)\,dx&=\lim_{t\to0^+}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-(x-z)^2/2t}\phi(x)\,dx\\\\
&=\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac1{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\phi(z+\sqrt{2t}\,x)\,dx
\end{align}$$
The Dominated convergence justifies the interchange of the order of the limit and the integral, which immediately yields
$$\lim_{t\to0^+}\int_{-\infty}^\infty G(t;x,z)\phi(x)\,dx=\phi(z)$$
And we are done!
When we have the double integral, we follow an anlogous development and arrive at the coveted result.

Hi yes your comment was helpful, just wondering is it valid to use the dominated convergence theorem straight away and then say G tends to the dirac delta or do you have to perform the substitution in order to use the dominated convergence theorem? Thanks

Pleased to hear.  To use the DCT, one needs to find a funtion 0f $x-z$ that is independent of $t$ and that dominates $\frac{e^{-(x-z)^2/2t}}{\sqrt{t}}$ for all $t>0$.   If such a function existed, then one could interchange the order of the limit and integration.  But note, that as $t\to 0^+$, $\frac{e^{-(x-z)^2/2t}}{\sqrt{t}}\to 0$.  So, we cannot immediately interchange the order of integration and limit.  Rather, we change dummy integration variables first.

And feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit of course.
